# Machine learning Model for predicting product purchase

Tags: machine-learning

I have this use case and want to build a ML model around it.
Based on the purchase history,I have to predict whether user will buy a product or not.

A product has these attributes:

- ItemCategory: eg: Shoes, Accessories,Jewellery
- Color: eg: Black,Red
- PriceBucket: eg: 500-1000,1000-1500

User has some % liking for each color,priceBucket,Itemcategory
eg: user u1 likes black 30%, red 20%, shoes 10%.
This % likings are calculated based on purchase history of the user.

Now suppose we match user u1's profile across all products, we have to predict whether user will buy that product or not.

```
       ItemCategory     PriceBucket  Color  Buy      
item1   30%               20%         10%   1
item2   20%               15%         30%   0   
item3   10%               50%         40%   1
```

Buy 1/0 denotes whether user has actually bought this item or not.

I have tried with tensorFlow's LinearClassifier but getting very low accuracy.
Please suggest what model can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for lower accuracy is many. 
I would suggest you to do some pre-processing steps before feeding in data into linear regressor model.

Since you just have only 3 dimensions/features in your data, you cannot get much information from it. It is very highly likely that your model get over-fit/underfit to any one feature among these three categories. Try adding more features if you have, or else increase number of training sample but still achieving decent result is very low because of low dimensionality.

Try and do some experiment with some other ensemble models like Decision Tree Classifier,Gaussian Naive Bayes, Gradient Boosting Classifier, SVM, Random forest,K-nearest-neighbors and perform cross validation to evaluate the performance of each classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for low accuracy could be having an imbalanced dataset, i.e. the ratio of buy values (0,1) is  greater than 2. If this is the case, use simple techniques such as under-sampling and then try different classification models on it. In your case, random forest probably will do a good job; play around with the parameters to avoid under/over fitting.